# How to view name and score on HTML from Firebase with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

How do i view this data in HTML in a tabulated format?

Answer (score 2):

try this,

## html

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="dataFetch">
       <table border="1" id="fetch">
          <tr>
             <th>Name</td>
             <th>Value</td>
           </tr>
       </table>
     </div>

  <script>
   // Initialize Firebase...

  </script>
   <script src="customer.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

## js

```
var table = document.getElementById('fetch');

var rowIndex = 1;
//var user_name = document.getElementById('user_name')
function serch(){


var data = firebase.database().ref('Users').child("Customers");
  data.once('value',function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
      var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();

      var row = table.insertRow(rowIndex);
      var cellId = row.insertCell(0);
      var cellName = row.insertCell(1);

      cellId.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childKey));
      cellName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData));

      rowIndex = rowIndex + 1;

    });
});
}
```

hope it's help full.

Comment: thanks a lot. How about viewing an image from firebase?

Comment: chech out this link,https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files  hope help for you